# location of $http.get('xxx/xxx/xxx', parameter)

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs. I'm working on a angularjs project which was started by other ppl. In the code, some functions are defined as the format $http('url', parameters). The urls are something like 'abc/def/hijk'. I want to modify the functions but I cannot find the location of the urls. where can I find the source files given the links? thanks.

Comment: `find . -type f -name '*.js' -exec grep 'abc/def/hijk' {} \; -print`

Comment: There's not necessarily a correlation between an URL and a file on disk. Is there a router? Start there.

Comment: Thanks phil and mpen

Answer (score 0):

Is this more of an environment/domain question?

$http is just an angular core service for make [http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) requests.

When you say

> I want to modify the functions but I cannot find the location of the urls. where can I find the source files given the links?

That is a very open ended question. If for example my angular site is hosted at http://mysite.local and the links looks like $http.get('/someUrl', config), then I would visit http://mysite.local/someUrl to see what is there. If it is in fact connecting to the same domain then ping it.

```
ping mysite.local
```

Whatever IP address you get back you may be able to resolve the hostname

```
ping -a 192.168.0.80
```

If this was a windows machine you could rdc and check the iis instance, otherwise ssh and check whats hosting on port 80?

Essentially what I'm getting at is... we don't no where your predecessor may have stored source or what your environment is setup like but with some investigation you may be able to shed some light.

Comment: Thanks. I finally found the files. It's mappings between the urls and functions. I will also try your method. Thanks a lot.